# Python 3: Saving API Results into CSV

Tags: python-3.x, api, csv

I'm writing a script which requires a daily updated CSV source file which lists many movie details and have decided to use Python3 to create and update it even though I don't know too much about it.

I believe I've got the code down to pull the information via TheMovieDB.org's API that I need, but currently can only get it to echo the results and not save in a CSV.  Below are a couple of questions I have, the code that I currently have, and an example of it's current output.

**Questions:**
1. What do I need to do add to get the resulting data into a CSV?  I've tried many things but so far haven't gotten anything to work
2. What would I need to add so that rerunning the script would completely overwrite the CSV produced from the last run? (not append or error out)
3. *Optional*: Unless tedious or a pain, it would be nice to have a column for each of the values provided per title within the CSV.

Thanks!!

**Current Code**

```
import http.client
import requests
import csv
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.themoviedb.org")
payload = "{}"
conn.request("GET", "/3/discover/movie?page=20&include_video=false&include_adult=false&sort_by=primary_release_date.desc&language=en-US&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", payload)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

**Result That's Echoed from the above Current Code**

> {"page":20,"total_results":360846,"total_pages":18043,"results":[{"vote_count":0,"id":521662,"video":false,"vote_average":0,"title":"森のかたみ","popularity":1.098018,"poster_path":"/qmj1gJ33lF7BhEOWAvK0mt6hRGH.jpg","original_language":"ja","original_title":"森のかたみ","genre_ids":[],"backdrop_path":null,"adult":false,"overview":"","release_date":"2019-01-01"},{"vote_count":0,"id":518636,"video":false,"vote_average":0,"title":"Stadtkomödie:
>   Geschenkt","popularity":1.189812,"poster_path":null,"original_language":"de","original_title":"Stadtkomödie:
>   Geschenkt","genre_ids":[35],"backdrop_path":null,"adult":false,"overview":"","release_date":"2019-01-01"},{"vote_count":0,"id":520720,"video":false,"vote_average":0,"title":"Kim
>   Possible","popularity":1.188148,"poster_path":"/3QGHTLgNKRphu3bLvGpoTZ1Ce9U.jpg","original_language":"en","original_title":"Kim
>   Possible","genre_ids":[10751,28,12],"backdrop_path":null,"adult":false,"overview":"Live-action
>   film adaptation of the Disney Channel original series Kim
>   Possible.","release_date":"2019-01-01"},{"vote_count":0,"id":521660,"video":false,"vote_average":0,"title":"Speak
>   Low","popularity":1.098125,"poster_path":"/qYQQlizCTfD5km7GIrTWrBb4E9b.jpg","original_language":"ja","original_title":"小さな声で囁いて","genre_ids":[],"backdrop_path":null,"adult":false,"overview":"","release_date":"2019-01-01"},{"vote_count":0,"id":497834,"video":false,"vote_average":0,"title":"Saturday Fiction","popularity":1.148142,"poster_path":null,"original_language":"zh","original_title":"兰心大剧院","genre_ids":[],"backdrop_path":null,"adult":false,"overview":"An
>   actress working undercover for the Allies in 1941 Shanghai discovers
>   the Japanese plan to attack Pearl
>   Harbor.","release_date":"2019-01-01"},{"vote_count":0,"id":523461,"video":false,"vote_average":0,"title":"Wie
>   gut ist deine
>   Beziehung?","popularity":1.188171,"poster_path":null,"original_language":"de","original_title":"Wie
>   gut ist deine
>   Beziehung?","genre_ids":[35],"backdrop_path":null,"adult":false,"overview":"","release_date":"2019-01-01"},{"vote_count":0,"id":507118,"video":false,"vote_average":0,"title":"Schwartz &
>   Schwartz","popularity":1.345715,"poster_path":null,"original_language":"de","original_title":"Schwartz
>   &
>   Schwartz","genre_ids":[80],"backdrop_path":null,"adult":false,"overview":"","release_date":"2019-01-01"},{"vote_count":0,"id":505916,"video":false,"vote_average":0,"title":"Kuru","popularity":1.107158,"poster_path":null,"original_language":"ja","original_title":"来る","genre_ids":[],"backdrop_path":null,"adult":false,"overview":"After
>   the inexplicable message, at his workplace, of a mysterious death, a
>   man is introduced to a freelance writer and his
>   girlfriend.","release_date":"2019-01-01"},{"vote_count":0,"id":521028,"video":false,"vote_average":0,"title":"Tsokos:
>   Zersetzt","popularity":1.115739,"poster_path":null,"original_language":"de","original_title":"Tsokos:
>   Zersetzt","genre_ids":[53],"backdrop_path":null,"adult":false,"overview":"","release_date":"2019-01-01"},{"vote_count":0,"id":516910,"video":false,"vote_average":0,"title":"Rufmord","popularity":1.658291,"poster_path":null,"original_language":"de","original_title":"Rufmord","genre_ids":[18],"backdrop_path":null,"adult":false,"overview":"","release_date":"2019-01-01"},{"vote_count":0,"id":514224,"video":false,"vote_average":0,"title":"Shadows","popularity":1.289124,"poster_path":null,"original_language":"en","original_title":"Shadows","genre_ids":[16],"backdrop_path":null,"adult":false,"overview":"Plot
>   kept under
>   wraps.","release_date":"2019-01-01"},{"vote_count":0,"id":483202,"video":false,"vote_average":0,"title":"Eli","popularity":1.118757,"poster_path":null,"original_language":"en","original_title":"Eli","genre_ids":[27],"backdrop_path":null,"adult":false,"overview":"A
>   boy receiving treatment for his auto-immune disorder discovers that
>   the house he's living isn't as safe as he
>   thought.","release_date":"2019-01-01"},{"vote_count":0,"id":491287,"video":false,"vote_average":0,"title":"Untitled Lani Pixels
>   Project","popularity":1.951231,"poster_path":null,"original_language":"en","original_title":"Untitled
>   Lani Pixels
>   Project","genre_ids":[10751,16,12,35],"backdrop_path":null,"adult":false,"overview":"Evil
>   forces have invaded an isolated island and have targeted Patrick and
>   Susan's grandfather, Mr. Campbell. Guided by Jack, a charming Irish
>   rogue, the siblings end up on a dangerous journey filled with magic
>   and
>   mystery.","release_date":"2019-01-01"},{"vote_count":2,"id":49046,"video":false,"vote_average":0,"title":"All
>   Quiet on the Western
>   Front","popularity":6.197559,"poster_path":"/jZWVtbxyztDTSM0LXDcE6vdVTVC.jpg","original_language":"en","original_title":"All
>   Quiet on the Western
>   Front","genre_ids":[28,12,18,10752],"backdrop_path":null,"adult":false,"overview":"A
>   young German soldier's terrifying experiences and distress on the
>   western front during World War
>   I.","release_date":"2018-12-31"},{"vote_count":1,"id":299782,"video":false,"vote_average":0,"title":"The
>   Other Side of the
>   Wind","popularity":4.561363,"poster_path":"/vnfNbuyPqo5zJavqlgI3J50xJSi.jpg","original_language":"en","original_title":"The
>   Other Side of the
>   Wind","genre_ids":[35,18],"backdrop_path":null,"adult":false,"overview":"Orson
>   Welles' unfinished masterpiece, restored and assembled based on
>   Welles' own notes. During the last 15 years of his life, Welles, who
>   died in 1985, worked obsessively on the film, which chronicles a
>   temperamental film director—much like him—who is battling with the
>   Hollywood establishment to finish an iconoclastic
>   work.","release_date":"2018-12-31"},{"vote_count":0,"id":289600,"video":false,"vote_average":0,"title":"The
>   Sandman","popularity":3.329464,"poster_path":"/eju4vLNx9sSvscowmnKNLi3sFVe.jpg","original_language":"en","original_title":"The
>   Sandman","genre_ids":[27],"backdrop_path":"/zo67d5klQiFR3PCyvER39IMwZ73.jpg","adult":false,"overview":"THE
>   SANDMAN tells the story of Nathan, a young student in the city who
>   struggles to forget his childhood trauma at the hands of the serial
>   killer dubbed \"The Sandman.\" Nathan killed The Sandman years ago, on
>   Christmas Eve, after he witnessed the murder of his mother... until he
>   sees the beautiful woman who lives in the apartment across the way
>   dying at the hands of that same masked killer. This brutal murder
>   plunges Nathan into an odyssey into the night country of his past, his
>   dreams... and the buried secrets of The
>   Sandman.","release_date":"2018-12-31"},{"vote_count":0,"id":378177,"video":false,"vote_average":0,"title":"Luxembourg","popularity":1.179703,"poster_path":null,"original_language":"en","original_title":"Luxembourg","genre_ids":[],"backdrop_path":null,"adult":false,"overview":"The
>   story of a group of people living in a permanent nuclear winter in the
>   ruins of the old civilisation destroyed by an atomic
>   war.","release_date":"2018-12-31"},{"vote_count":0,"id":347392,"video":false,"vote_average":0,"title":"Slice","popularity":3.248065,"poster_path":"/ySWPZihd5ynCc1aNLQUXmiw5H2V.jpg","original_language":"en","original_title":"Slice","genre_ids":[35],"backdrop_path":"/rtL9nzXtSvo1MW05kho9oeimCdb.jpg","adult":false,"overview":"When
>   a pizza delivery driver is murdered on the job, the city searches for
>   someone to blame: ghosts? drug dealers? a disgraced
>   werewolf?","release_date":"2018-12-31"},{"vote_count":0,"id":438674,"video":false,"vote_average":0,"title":"Dragged
>   Across
>   Concrete","popularity":3.659627,"poster_path":"/p4tpV4nGeocuOKhp0enuiQNDvhi.jpg","original_language":"en","original_title":"Dragged
>   Across
>   Concrete","genre_ids":[18,80,53,9648],"backdrop_path":null,"adult":false,"overview":"Two
>   policemen, one an old-timer (Gibson), the other his volatile younger
>   partner (Vaughn), find themselves suspended when a video of their
>   strong-arm tactics becomes the media's cause du jour. Low on cash and
>   with no other options, these two embittered soldiers descend into the
>   criminal underworld to gain their just due, but instead find far more
>   than they wanted awaiting them in the
>   shadows.","release_date":"2018-12-31"},{"vote_count":0,"id":437518,"video":false,"vote_average":0,"title":"Friend
>   of the
>   World","popularity":4.189267,"poster_path":"/hf3LucIg7t7DUvgGJ9DjQyHcI4J.jpg","original_language":"en","original_title":"Friend
>   of the
>   World","genre_ids":[35,18,27,878,53,10752],"backdrop_path":null,"adult":false,"overview":"After
>   a catastrophic war, an eccentric general guides a filmmaker through a
>   ravaged bunker.","release_date":"2018-12-31"}]}

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import http.client
import csv
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.themoviedb.org")
payload = "{}"
conn.request("GET", "/3/discover/movie?page=20&include_video=false&include_adult=false&sort_by=primary_release_date.desc&language=en-US&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", payload)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
json_data = json.loads(data)
results=json_data["results"]
for item in results:
    print (item('vote_count'))
    #write code to get necessary objects to write in csv
```

This is a way how you can do it. Comment if you have any query.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a `JSON` object, so you can parse it into a python dictionary using:

```
import json
mydict = json.loads(data)
```

Probably the values you want are in `mydict[results]` which is another set of key:value pairs. Depending on how you want these you could use a CSV library or just iterate through them and the print the contents with a tab between them.

```
for item in vars["results"]:
    for k in item:
        print("{}\t{}".format(k,item.get(k)))
```

Comment: @usama-jamil, you beat me to it :^)